# Recommended Cross-Platform (Windows and Android) Project Set Up using OpenTK

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xamarin, xamarin.android, opentk

I am starting to develop a scientific software that I hope I will be able to run on multiple platforms. My plan is to use OpenTK for the rendering of the scientific models and plots. As of the moment I have a prototype that runs on Windows using OpenTK 1.1 libraries from http://www.opentk.com/ (a simpler version just with OpenTK and a more complicated one with OpenTK + WindwosForms). I am trying to port that prototype to Android.

It seems that the syntax using by the Xamarin.Android OpenTK library is nearly identical to the one that I am currently using for Windows (with the only difference that OpenGL -> OpenGL ES and GameWindow -> AndroidGameView) so the porting shouldn't be an issue. However, I was hoping that I could avoid a copy-paste method and get a more permanent solution having a shared OpenTK code between the Windows and the Android version.

I have read trough the Xamarin documentation about the shared vs PCL methods for cross-platform development. However, I still struggle to figure out how to set-up a Visual Studio solution with an Android and Windows project and a shared code that will include OpenTK. Is that even possible and can someone give me an example of how to do it? I did explore an example I found for rendering a rotating cube using OpenTK for a shared Android/iOS project (http://developer.xamarin.com/content/TexturedCubeES30/) but in my case I need to use a different OpenTK library for the Windows and for the Android project.

I also found this [Do the Android and iOS versions of OpenTK have the same API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21976102/do-the-android-and-ios-versions-of-opentk-have-the-same-api) discussion. It is very similar to what I would like to do but in my case I am trying to setup a project for Windows and Android (for now).

Can I use only one OpenTK library (which one?) that is being called from both the Android and the Windows project and what will be the right way to set-up both projects so they share the same OpenTK code. This is the first time I am dealing with writing a cross-platform code so I am a bit lost.

**Edit:** I was able to get a prototype running using Shared Xamarin project and compiler flags as proposed below. Code was indeed not very pretty at places but I got over 70% code re-usability between the two platforms so it was worth the effort. This is how I used the compiler flags in case someone is looking for the same thing (credit to SKall from the Xamarin forums):

```cs
#if __ANDROID__
using OpenTK.Graphics.ES11;
#else
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;
#endif
```

I used the #if syntax similarly where there were small differences between the syntax of the routines.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem like OpenTK has its logic inside of a PCL in the first place, so your plans on putting it there are going to get hard to achieve.

However, if you split out your code, such that most of it is contained in classes, which are not highly dependent on the underlying platform, you will be able to create a Class Library Project for each platform and link your files between the platform specific projects. Inside of the classes it contains you will use `#if` definitions to choose whether to use `AndroidGameView` or `GameWindow` and the same goes for other platform specific types. It will make the code ugly, but this is the alternative to PCL.

You could try to see how much of the OpenTK code compiles inside of a PCL and inject the platform specific stuff at runtime, but it will require considerably more work from you. However, it will make the code a lot more cleaner to look at.

To ease the file linking, you could make one of those Shared Projects and chuck in all of the logic in there.

Some more info about code sharing here: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/sharing_code_options/

Dependency injection: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

Comment: The desktop version of OpenTK can be converted to PCL easily enough (`#define MINIMAL` in the project settings). However, the Android version depends on Xamarin.Android which is not a PCL. Using a shared project is your best bet, but I'm open to ideas on possible solutions inside OpenTK itself.

Comment: Yes, I am exploring the Shared Project approach using #if wherever needed. I think it may be the easiest way to go about it. I guess I am on the right track then. I may update my question later with some comments on what I have learned once I get a prototype running or if I run into any serious issues.